# rerender Refreshes the repeat, need to reassign values

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

When i click on "Add another session" Button it Adds new group of date and time binded in repeat and it rerenders. Repeat is rerendered but obiously values will be null. I want to retain those values or Reinitialise those values. How could i achive this ?

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!addWebinarTime}" name="addWebinarTimejs" reRender="optpnl_addedtimes"/>
<apex:outputpanel id="optpnl_addedtimes">
 <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(occursType == 'Custom schedule')}">
  <apex:repeat value="{!WebinarTimeRows}" id="webinartimes" var="webinartime">
     <apex:input type="date" value="{!webinartime.StartDate}" styleClass="form-control" />
     <apex:selectList styleClass="form-control" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!webinartime.EndTime}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Dates}"/>
     </apex:selectList>
     <apex:selectList styleClass="form-control" multiselect="false" size="1"  value="{!webinartime.Startampm}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AmPm}"/>
     </apex:selectList>
     <apex:selectList styleClass="form-control" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!webinartime.EndTime}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Dates}"/>
     </apex:selectList>
     <apex:selectList styleClass="form-control" multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!webinartime.Endampm}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!AmPm}"/>
     </apex:selectList>
  </apex:repeat>
 </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:outputpanel id="optpnl_addnewtimebutton">
 <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!(occursType == 'Custom schedule')}">
   <apex:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-primary" onclick="addWebinarTimejs(); return false;" value="Add another session"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
</apex:outputpanel>

Apex:
public List<WebinarMultipleTimeRow> WebinarTimeRows {get; set;} 
public PageReference addWebinarTime()
{
    WebinarMultipleTimeRow obj_WebinarMultipleTimeRow = new WebinarMultipleTimeRow('','','','','');
    WebinarTimeRows.add(obj_WebinarMultipleTimeRow);
    return null;
}
public List<SelectOption> getDates() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    options.add(new SelectOption('Select','Select'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('01','01'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('02','02'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('03','03'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('04','04'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('05','05'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('06','06'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('07','07'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('08','08'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('09','09'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('11','11'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('12','12'));
    return options;
}
public class WebinarMultipleTimeRow {
    public String StartDate        {get; set;}
    public String  StartTime       {get; set;}
    public String  EndTime       {get; set;}
    public String  Startampm {get; set;}
    public String  Endampm {get; set;}
    public WebinarMultipleTimeRow()
    {
    }
    public WebinarMultipleTimeRow(String StartDate ,String  StartTime,String  EndTime,String  Startampm,String  Endampm) {
     this.StartDate =StartDate;
     this.StartTime=StartTime;
     this.EndTime=EndTime;
     this.Startampm=Startampm;
     this.Endampm= Endampm; 

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it should be causing it, but why are you calling an actionFunction from a commandLink? Why not call the action directly on the commandLink?

Comment: I want partial page updates. i want to rerender that much part of VF. But values should retain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WebinarMultipleTimeRow {
    public Date StartDate        {get; set;}
    public String  StartTime       {get; set;}
    }
```

> Need to change String to Date

Answer (score 1):

Providing your controller has this property:

```
public List<WebinarMultipleTimeRow> WebinarTimeRows {get; set;}
```

and you have an `apex:form`, the existing row values should be preserved during the re-render.

If you do have the above in your page, I suggest you use your browser's "Developer Tools" "Network" tab to watch the requests and responses to better understand what is going on.

(Note it would be more conventional to use the `action` attribute of the `apex:commandLink` to directly invoke the controller method.)

Comment: i have public List<WebinarMultipleTimeRow> WebinarTimeRows {get; set;} 
in my class